# Spring Integration - Break the flow if value is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

So I have a configuration in my Spring Integration like below :

**POS -> invoke SI by passing ID -> Get Details of that ID -> Hit the API URL**

Now what I'm trying to achieve is,

**POS -> invoke SI by passing ID -> Get Details of that ID -> *If not null (If null, then break the flow)* -> Hit the API URL**

And my config file looks like this :

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="CNInvokeFromPOS" 
    supported-methods="GET"
    request-channel="CNInvokeRequest"
    reply-channel="CNInvokeResponse"
    path="/postToCN/{CNId}"
    mapped-response-headers="Return-Status, Return-Status-Msg, HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS"
    reply-timeout="10000" >
    <int-http:header name="CNId" expression="#pathVariables.CNId"/>
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator id="motorCNInvokeActivator"
                input-channel="CNInvokeRequest"
                output-channel="CNInvokeResponse"
                ref="apiCNService"
                method="getCNDetailsById"
                requires-reply="true"
                send-timeout="10000"/>

<int:transformer input-channel="CNInvokeResponse"
        ref="apiCNTransformer"
        method="retrieveJson" 
        output-channel="CNInvokeRequest"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="CNInvokeRequest" reply-channel="CNInvoketransformerOut"
    url="http://someurl" http-method="POST"
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>    

<int:service-activator 
            input-channel="CNInvoketransformerOut" 
            output-channel="CNInvokeobjTransformerOut"
            ref="apiCNService" 
            method="responseCN"
            send-timeout="10000"/>
```

I know about error channel, but the problem here is, if the returned value is null, I don't want to continue or retry! Just break it and stop the flow. Can someone point me towards the possible ways to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Returning null ends the flow; no further action is taken, although with your configuration, the inbound gateway thread will wait 10 seconds for the reply before timing out.

Then a 500 status is returned to the caller; you can change that behavior with the `reply-timeout-status-code-expression`.

Since you are using only direct channels, you can safely set the reply timeout to zero - the timer does not start until the thread returns to the gateway.

Comment: If I return null from apiCNTransformer.retrieveJson method, it should end the flow? Let me try it.

Comment: Transformers can't return `null`; I thought you were talking about `apiCNService`. However, `apiCNTransformer` can be invoked as a service activator instead, which can return null. Transformers typically don't have conditional logic in them, they simply transform the data. If it examines the data and decides whether or not to proceed, it's not really "just" a transformer, so a service activator is more appropriate anyway. Or, you can add a filter to the flow and make the transformer a true transformer.